# Proving $\displaystyle\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt {2m+1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{(2m+1)n}}{\sqrt {1-t^{2n}}}\,dt\ $ exists and is positive

Tags: real-analysis, integration, elliptic-integrals

I’m new here, sorry if my question isn’t formatted correctly. I’m stuck on exercise 1.2.1 in this: http://users.mai.liu.se/vlatk48/teaching/lect2-agm.pdf (page 16), which asks the reader to prove the convergence of the following limits:

$$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt {2m+1}}\prod_{j=1}^{m}\frac{2jn+1}{(2j-1)n+1}$$

and

$$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt {2m+1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{(2m+1)n}}{\sqrt {1-t^{2n}}}\,dt$$

exist and are greater than 0.

I can do the product; it’s just expressing $\frac{1}{\sqrt {2m+1}}$ as a product from 1 to m, squaring the whole expression, and performing the sum test, but I can’t figure out the integral. The best I’ve gotten is that I can reduce it to a special case.

First, note that since the integral runs from 0 to 1,  $\sqrt {1-t^{2n}}$ is larger for larger n, while $t^{(2m+1)n}$ is smaller for larger n, so the expression converges for all n if and only if it converges for 1.

Then, make the following change of variables

$$u=t^n$$
$$dt=\frac{du}{nt^{n-1}}$$

The division by $t^{n-1}$ only makes the integrand larger, since t is between 0 and 1, and n is a constant with respect to the limit, so the limit is greater than 0 for all n iff it is greater than 0 for n=1.

But despite thinking about it all day, I can’t even begin to figure out how to crack the special case. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how you determined the convergence of the first limit, was there an expression for $\sqrt{2m+1}$?

Comment: @user100101212 sure. Since the terms in the product are all positive, the limit of the squares of partial products is the square of the limit. So if we square it, and use $\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2m+1}=\prod_{j=1}^{m}\frac{2j-1}{2j+1}$ (since all the other terms cancel out), we're left with $\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2jn+1)^{2}(2j-1)}{((2j-1)n+1)^2(2j+1)}$ for the limit of the squares, if they converge. Then, we use the result that $\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}p_j$ converges iff $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} 1-p_j$ converges. Straightforward algebra shows the numerators in the sum are...

Comment: ... linear in j, while the denominators are cubic in j, and neither have any positive  integer zeros, so we get convergence of the sum, hence convergence of the square of our original product, hence convergence of the product we're after. That the product is greater than 0 follows from the fact that the terms in the product approach 1, and none of them are 0

Comment: Not an answer, but do you know that Wolfram Alpha calculates your integral explicitly? It also calculates that it behaves asymptotically like $m^{-1/2}$, showing that your limit exist. Of course, I wouldn't know how to calculate what it displays.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thanks for that! The explicit integral seems to involve hypergeometric functions, though, and I'm hoping an introductory text on elliptic integrals and elliptic functions doesn't assume prior knowledge of the properties of hypergeometric functions. I might just do a deep dive on those if I don't get any answers on this, though.

Comment: I agree. Just mentioning that because I cannot really see how to show the behavior.

Comment: Wait a second, if I plug in the definite integral it only involves the gamma function. That might be the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v=t^{2n}$. Then $dv=2nt^{2n-1}\,dt$. By [definition of the Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), and expressing the Beta function interms of the Gamma function, your integral is 
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{(2m+1)n}}{\sqrt {1-t^{2n}}}\,dt=\frac1{2n}\int_0^1v^{m+\frac12}(1-v)^{-1/2}\,dv=\frac1{2n}\,B(m+\tfrac32,\tfrac12)=\frac{\Gamma(m+\tfrac32)\Gamma(\tfrac12)}{2n\Gamma(m+2)}.
$$

Thus, using [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Approximation), we get for big $m$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{2m+1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{(2m+1)n}}{\sqrt {1-t^{2n}}}\,dt
&= \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2n}\,\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{m+3/2}}\left(\frac{m+3/2}e\right)^{m+3/2}}{\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{m+2}}\left(\frac{m+2}e\right)^{m+2}}\,\sqrt{2m+1}\\ \ \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi e}}{2n}\,\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{m+3/2}}\,\left({m+3/2}\right)^{m+3/2}}{\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{m+2}}\,\left( {m+2}\right)^{m+3/2}}\,\frac{\sqrt{2m+1}}{\sqrt{m+2}}\\ \ \\
&\xrightarrow[m\to\infty]{}\frac{\sqrt{\pi e}}{2n}\,1\,\frac1{\sqrt e}\,\sqrt2
=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n^2}}
\end{align}
I find all this fairly sophisticated for a casual exercise, but I didn't check your source carefully for context.

---

**Comment 1:**

If your sources for the beta function differ from the Wikipedia article (since you used the sine), you can push your formula to arbitrary positive $n$: you simply do the substitution $t^{n}=\sin\theta$. Then $nt^{n-1}\,dt=\cos\theta\,d\theta$. So
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{(2m+1)n}}{\sqrt {1-t^{2n}}}\,dt
&=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{t^{(2m+1)n}}{nt^{n-1}}\,d\theta
=\frac1n\,\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\sin^{2mn+1}}\theta\,d\theta\\ \ \\
\end{align}

---

**Comment 2:** a manipulation with partial fractions that removes the singularity at 1.

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{(2m+1)n}dt}{\sqrt {1-t^{2n}}}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{2mn-n+1}\,t^{2n-1}dt}{\sqrt {1-t^{2n}}}\\ \ \\
&=-\left.\vphantom{\int}\frac {t^{2mn-n+1}\sqrt {1-t^{2n }}}{n}\right|_0^1
+\tfrac {2mn-n+1}{n}\int_0^1t^{2mn-n}\sqrt {1-t^{2n}}\,dt\\ \ \\
&=\tfrac {2mn-n+1}{n}\int_0^1t^{2mn-n}\sqrt {1-t^{2n}}\,dt.
\end{align}

Comment: Where did you get the extra factor of $\sqrt{e}$ in the denominator?

Comment: I agree that it's a little strange to assume knowledge of other special functions like the gamma and beta function when the topic is elliptic integrals, but the very next exercise asks the reader to provide an alternate proof of a certain identity starting with the gamma and beta functions, so clearly the author assumes at least some prior knowledge of these functions.

Comment: Makes sense. The $e$ in the numerator comes from simplifying the ones that come from Stirling. The one in the denominator is $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\frac{m+3/2}{m+2}\right)^{m+3/2}=\frac1{\sqrt e}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I believe I've figured it out. Since I've already shown how this reduces to a special case, let's start by assuming n is 1, giving us
$$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt {2m+1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{2m+1}dt}{\sqrt {1-t^{2}}}$$

Make the change of variables 
$$t=sin(\theta)$$
$$dt=cos(\theta)d\theta $$

which leaves

$$\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt {2m+1}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} sin(\theta)^{2m+1}d\theta=\lim_{m\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt {2m+1}\frac{1}{2}B(m+1,\frac{1}{2})$$

Now, writing the beta function in terms of the gamma function, we have

$$\frac{1}{2}B(m+1,{\frac{1}{2}})=\frac{\Gamma(m+1)\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{2\Gamma(m+\frac{3}{2})}=\frac{\Gamma(m+1)\sqrt{\pi}}{2\Gamma(m+\frac{3}{2})}$$

Using Stirling's approximation for both of the gamma functions, this asymptotically approaches

$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{m+1}}$$

as m tends to infinity.Plugging this back into our original equation gives a nonzero limit of $\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}$ for the case of n=1, which proves that some limit exists for the other cases. I'd be happy for someone to check my work, but I think this is it. Thanks to Martin Argerami for pointing me towards Wolfram Alpha.

Edit: Corrected errors.